# Finding Solr documents that intersect with a defined Radius

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, polygon, intersection

We are using Apache Solr 5.x, and we currently have a bunch of defined shapes. Polygons, Circles, etc. These all correspond to a document, each shape of coordinates does.

What I want to know is - is it possible to provide a `circle`, that is - a (lat,lng) pair along with a `Radius` for that circle - and then find all documents that have an intersection with that circle?

I have tried a variety of options, most recently this one:

```
solr_index_wkt:"IsWithin(CIRCLE((149.39999999999998 -34.92 d=0.44964028776978415))) distErrPct=0.0"
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
"msg": "Unknown Shape definition [CIRCLE((149.39999999999998 -34.92 d=0.44964028776978415))]",
```

Really stumped on this one.

**update**

the *solr_index_wkt* is the field that is defining the 'bounding boxes' for the polygons, circles and stuff on the indexed documents.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and I kept banging my head against my keyboard until I found this little gem. I'm sure you're probably using solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType in your schema.xml file. You need to set the format attribute to "LEGACY". It should then recognize Circle in your queries!

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
       spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
       autoIndex="true"
       validationRule="repairBuffer0"
       format="LEGACY"
       distErrPct="0.025"
       maxDistErr="0.001"
       distanceUnits="miles" />
```

Comment: Could explain why ?