# SOLR spatial query with distance value of queried document

Tags: solr

I'm trying to do a spatial query on a set of documents which have a radius field and a location field:

```
<field name="placeOfWork_coords" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
<field name="radius" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
```

I would like to check if an arbitrary latlng point is within the radius of this document. I have only worked with static distances for the `d` query parameter so far, so I would like to know how I can reference the radius field of the document in the query, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you'll have to index the shape itself instead of having it as two separate fields; index a Circle with the given center point and radius. You can use a [RptWithGeometrySpatialField](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/spatial-search.html#rpt) field, and [index your shape as](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4-Indexing):

```
Circle(4.56,1.23 d=0.0710)
```

The latter distance is in degrees, to convert to miles/km/meters, use the formulas provided on the wiki linked above:

> **Units, Conversion**
>
> Degrees to desired units: `Math.toRadians(degrees) *
>   earthRadiusInTheUnitsYouWant`
>
> Degrees to kilometers: `degrees * 111.1951`
>
> Degrees to miles: `degrees * 69.09341`

The RptWithGeometrySpatialField should be the most accurate option. When you're querying, you use the `Intersects` operator:

```
&fq={!field f=geo}Intersects(-74.093 41.042)
```

.. should work. You might need a POINT type or similar to wrap the coordinates, but as far as I remember that isn't necessary. Previously it was `lon lat` at least if there was no comma and `lat,lon` if there was, so make sure to use the correct format.

Comment: I also had to add the attribute `format="LEGACY"` to the `fieldType` as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092196/finding-solr-documents-that-intersect-with-a-defined-radius). Otherwise there was an `Unknown Shape definition` error.